# Express - How to modify request then redirect to another route?

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, request, middleware

I'm looking for a way to modify my request before redirect to another route in my express.js app.

I tried two approachs to do this :
1)

```
 #users.coffee
 router.use '/:id', (req, res, next) ->
   req.currentUser = req.params.id
   req.url = '/'
   next()

 #app.coffee
 app.use '/users', require('./routes/users')
 app.get '/', (req, res) ->
   locals = {}
   if req.currentUser
     locals.currentUser = req.currentUser
   res.render 'index', locals
```

2)

```
 #users.coffee
 router.use '/:id', (req, res, next) ->
   req.currentUser = req.params.id
   res.redirect '/'

 #app.coffee
 app.use '/users', require('./routes/users')
 app.get '/', (req, res) ->
   locals = {}
   if req.currentUser
     locals.currentUser = req.currentUser
   res.render 'index', locals
```

With the first approach, there is no redirection and with the second, the page is not rendered.

Comment: In the first approach can you try req.url = '/' rather than res.url = '/'

Comment: it was a syntax error. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal which i wanted achieve is probably impossible. The url sent by the client request can't be modified. I can only send a status 302 and a redirect url then the client emits a new get request. So there are two different requests .
However I can turn the slash format of the url in query.

```
#users.coffee
 router.get '/:id', (req, res) ->
   res.redirect '/?user:'+req.params.id
```